# How to replace url(...) in rollup'd CSS with data URI?

Tags: javascript, css, bundling-and-minification, rollupjs

Using rollup and the postcss plugin, I am able to inject CSS into my bundle. However, my CSS references some image files e.g. `background-image: url(./images/my-image.svg);`.

How can I configure postcss/rollup to replace instances of CSS `url(...)` with data URIs and thereby embed the SVGs inside of the bundle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [postcss-url](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-url) plugin to achieve this.

Install the `postcss-url` plugin to your project and add it to the postcss plugins array in your rollup config.

```js
const url = require('postcss-url');
const postcss = require("rollup-plugin-postcss");

export default {
  plugins: [
    postcss({
      plugins: [
        url({
          url: "inline", // enable inline assets using base64 encoding
          maxSize: 10, // maximum file size to inline (in kilobytes)
          fallback: "copy", // fallback method to use if max size is exceeded
        }),
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

You can customize the fallback mechanism based on your needs.

Comment: Did you mean `const url = require("postcss-url");` ?

Comment: @avi-software Yes. I have fixed the answer now. Thanks for pointing it out.