# Add font-face via css-modules to rollup bundle

Tags: font-face, rollup, css-modules

So I'm trying to create a component library with rollup and I want a font to work that I have added via font-face.

I looked at this https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/url but I can only find examples when using styled-components, and I have css-modules.

Then I found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61790221
But it does not seem to do anything when I add it.

I add my font-face in one of my components like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('../../shared/fonts/my-font.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

How can I add it to my rollup bundle?

My rollup config looks like this:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';
/* import url from '@rollup/plugin-url'; */
import url from 'postcss-url';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';

import pkg from './package.json';

export default [
  {
    input: './src/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        file: pkg.main,
        format: 'cjs',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: pkg.module,
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }),
      babel({
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      }),
      postcss(),
      image(),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: './types/index.d.ts',
    output: [{ file: './dist/mycomponents.d.ts', format: 'es' }],
    plugins: [dts()],
  },
];
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `@rollup/plugin-url`, we could able to add fonts files to rollup bundle. In your `rollup config` file add the following.

This will look for all `woff, woff2, ttf` files and add it to the bundle.

```
import url from '@rollup/plugin-url';

plugins: [
    ...
    ...

    url({
      include: ['**/*.woff', '**/*.woff2', '**/*.ttf'],
      limit: Infinity,
      fileName: '[dirname][name][extname]',
    }),

    ...
    ...
  ],
```